# I am trying to get image from camera and insert into sqlite database

Tags: java, android

[What am ai missing, on my onActivityResult method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsdhP.png)

Is there any labrary update in the documentation? I am trying to  add crop fuction but get activiy, getUri and Picasso is not working. I have followed all the tutorials is not showing any error

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE){
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Uri resultUri=result.getUri();
            Picasso.with(this).load(resultUri).into(image);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: share the actual code so that we can copy it directly...sharing the image won't solve your problem